# What is this fruit?

Tags: fruits

My friend asked me whether I recognize the fruit in the picture and I don't what it is. Does anyone recognize it?

[image: The picture of the fruit]

Comment: Its not a fruit and dont try to eat it unless you want to get very sick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Osage orange , ( maclura pomifera ) not a fruit but a seed pod. Common in hedge rows in south central US. Other names hedge apple and bodark.  Not a "large" tree. The wood has been used to make wood long bows.

Comment: I find it interesting that the fruit was meant to be eaten by ground sloths. Here's an interesting read on that and other "megafauna" trees: https://www.americanforests.org/magazine/article/trees-that-miss-the-mammoths/

Comment: Now primarily eaten by lawnmowers.